Execution failed for task ':android_intent_plus:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. > error: invalid source release: 17

Hey, I get this error every time. My JDK version is 17, and Flutter is the latest.
Android Studion info --

Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.19072.14.2412.12360217, built on September 12, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 6
Non-Bundled Plugins:
org.jetbrains.plugins.go-template (241.14494.150)
Dart (241.18808)
com.localizely.flutter-intl (1.18.5-2023.2)
idea.plugin.protoeditor (241.15989.49)
dev.polek.adbwifi (1.2.6)
com.intellij.plugins.vscodekeymap (241.14494.150)
com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.3(241)-9)
com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.15)
org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.ide (1.6.2)
com.github.copilot (1.5.24.6840)
io.flutter (81.0.2)

I got this error with every packages which use JDK 17
I changed jdk veriosn updated android studio. But it's not working

Did you open the only "android" folder of your flutter project with Android Studio to let the IDE automatically download and install the gradle?

I fixed it. I just added the JDK 17 path to the gradle.properties file. and it's work smoothly
